# Angular 6 routing load using SSR

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I have just migrated an Angular 5 app to Angular 6 and I have created a brand new component where I have a question for. My app has `SSR` configured and I can see the rendering working fine.

My new component does the following on the `ngOnInit`:

1. calls a http using a standard get and resolving a promise
2. checks if `isPlatformBrowser` to subscribe to `window.resize` event

If I navigate to my main page `www.website.com` and then I navigate to the angular component I just described above it all works fine. Let's say the route is `www.website.com/myComponent`.

However if I open a new browser and do `www.website.com/myComponent` the application hangs. Eventually the webserver returns 504 however the API (where I make the HTTP call) does not get hit and I can see in the logs of the app: `Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error`

I was investigating what could it be and compared the component OnInit against another one that does a similar thing. The difference was that the HTTP called was also wrapped inside the isPlatformBrowser code.

My question is: Do all HTTP calls need to be wrapped up inside isPlatformBrowser for SSR from now on? Could it be something else going on such as a bug somewhere that does not resolve correctly the platform browser stuff and as this is asynchronous code (Promise being awaited) breaks the HTTP call or leaves it in a bad state?

My Angular version is 6.1.0
SSR 6.0.0

Comment: Going through the details I suspect that there might be problem with the routing  of you myComponent. Share the error log and routing configuration for the component which has problem.

Comment: Is there any error server side,  for the process running serve.js/ts  nodejs server?

Comment: eduPeeth the routing works fine to that component when there is no HTTP call being made there. Also, when there is and I do ng serve, it works fine locally so that makes me think there is something related to the SSR.

@David I'm going to get the error of the Node Express Server. Note that I'm running a PM2 docker container but that doesn't make any difference

Comment: Yeah just check `pm2 logs`

Comment: The actual PMA log error does not say much. Perhaps I need to change the way I print the error: 0|my-app | Error getting stuff  Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error.

My nginx logs:
*1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: XXX, server

And my API does not have any error

Comment: just to add a bit more info, I have an NGINX reverse proxy sending requests to multiple containers. NGINX itself is also a container

Comment: Another interesting test: If I run the "my-app" container locally and point to PROD, I don't have that error either, so that only happens when I'm running in the PROD environment behind the nginx reverse proxy